# Does any browser implement the datalist data attribute?

Tags: xml, html, html-datalist

The HTML5 element `<datalist>` has an attribute `data="filename.xml"` where filename.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<select xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <option value="someValue" />
  <option value="anotherValue" />
</select>
```

However, this seems to have not yet been implemented (tried Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera).
Does any browser implement it? (Will any soon?)

Edit: [source](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_datalist_tag.cfm)

Comment: What `data` attribute? Can’t find such an attribute in HTML5 CR, HTML 5.1 Nightly, or WHATWG Living HTML. Is it even a proposal that has been made in public?

Comment: I guess you are right, I found this: lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/help-whatwg.org/2010-November/000679.html

Answer (score 2):

You can check support for datalist here:

http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist

Someone else might provide information about the data attribute specifically.

There is a [polyfill](http://css-tricks.com/relevant-dropdowns-polyfill-for-datalist/) here, which also mentions browser support (or lack of).

Comment: ...which shows that <datalist> is supported; but my question is about the "data=" attribute of <datalist>.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same article and was surprised to read that the `data` attribute isn't a part of the official spec, but I guess that is to be expected when relying on information from blog posts.

Anyways, I liked that implementation and decided to write a JavaScript function to make it work.

```js
window.addEventListener( 'load', function( ) {
    var dataList = document.getElementById( 'myDataList' );
    getDataList( dataList, dataList.getAttribute( 'data' ) );
} );

function getDataList( dataList, dataFile )
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest( );
    var options, parser, xml;

    http.onreadystatechange = function( )
    {
        if( http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200 )
        {
            if( window.DOMParser )
            {
                parser = new DOMParser( );
                xml = parser.parseFromString( http.responseText, "text/xml" );
            }
            else
            {
                xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
                xml.async = false;
                xml.loadXML( http.responseText ); 
            }

            options = xml.getElementsByTagName( 'option' );

            for( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ )
            {
                var option = document.createElement( 'option' );
                option.value = options[i].value;
                dataList.appendChild( option );
            }
        }
    }

    http.open( "GET", dataFile, true );
    http.send( );
}
```